# Symfony2 User Roles (BETA2)

Tags: symfony, user-roles

What's the appropriate way to add a user to a role.. for every new user, do I have to do:

```
$em->getRepository('MyBundle:Role')->findOneBy(array('name' => 'ROLE_USER'))
```

every time?

I'm not too much of a fan of how large UserBundle is.... and I don't use XML.  I'm using YML/Annotations, so the UserBundle is pretty hard to follow for certain things.

So yes, what's the best / cleanest way to do a user signup and associate him to a default role?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way I've found is just to define `roles` as a field of type `array` on your User object. Then, when you're creating the user (on registration or whatnot), it's as simple as

```
$roles = array('ROLE_USER');
$user->setRoles($roles);
```

I've put together a mockup of my user registration process in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/993460). It's not fully functional (I can flesh it out later if needed), but it should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Note that the examples in the gist are for Beta2; if you're using a previous version, some things will be different (annotations, for example)

Comment: Yep, it looks similar to what I have going on.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a couple of blog posts on roles, a simple solution http://blog.jmoz.co.uk/symfony2-fosuserbundle-roles and http://blog.jmoz.co.uk/symfony2-fosuserbundle-role-entities